# Building with Maven fails when trying to install Hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop and trying to build using Maven.

when I type the command `mvn package -pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`, I get the following error:

```
failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5 process on project apache-maven error rendering velocity resource. I
Invocation of method 'getresourceAsFile' in class org.code.hause.plexus.resource.defaultresourceManager through exception org.code.hause.plexus.resource.loader.resourceNotFoundException. 
could not found resource 'https://galssfish.java.net.
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Please post the POM. It will be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: excuse me. I am new in hadoop and I do not know where I can find pom. I am just installing hadoop. where can I find pom?

Comment: It is usually located in the same directory that you run the `mvn` command in.

Comment: pom is really long and this textbox does not allow me to paste pom text into it.shall I post some sections of pom?

Comment: I understand. Could you please add the last Maven execution leading up to the error text you already provided? Your execution should look like this: `--- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:xxx (default-XXX) @ apache-maven ---` As far as the POM concerns, if you could post the configuration part for the `maven-remote-resources-plugin` and we'll see if we can something out of it.

Comment: Could it be as easy as the URL `https://galssfish.java.net` being misspelled? `https://glassfish.java.net` seems more correct....